# Ejecucion de macro con python

Tags: python, excel

actualmente estoy copiando informacion de una hoja de un libro a otra hoja de otro libro, esto lo ejecuto con una macro, la cual me funciona al ejecutarla desde el excel, pero al tratar de automatizarlo con python este me arroja un erro de atributo, pero no me queda claro, ya que el código que uso para correr macros me funciona con varioas de otros archivos sin problemas y me guarda, pero en esta me da error:

Este es mi código en python:

```
try:
    excel_macro = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel_path = os.path.expanduser("D:/Q_DIARIO/Query_Diario_ESTRUCTURA.xlsm")
    workbook = excel_macro.Workbooks.Open(Filename = excel_path, ReadOnly =1)
    excel_macro.Application.Run("Query_Diario_ESTRUCTURA.xlsm!Módulo5.CopyExportD")
    time.sleep(60)
    workbook.Save()
    workbook.Close(SaveChanges=1)
    excel_macro.Application.Quit()
    excel_macro.Quit()
    del excel_macro
    print (log_reg+"Macro EliminarCancelados ejecutada en exportD")
except Exception  as err:
    print("Error tratando de ejecutar EliminarCancelados ejecutada en exportD")
    print(err)
```

Este el de vba de excel, el cual lo ejecuto y me funciona con desde excel:

```
Dim Workbook As Excel.Workbook

Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Q_DIARIO\exportD.xlsm"
Range("A1:AI1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Q_DIARIO\Query_Diario_ESTRUCTURA.xlsm"
Windows("Query_Diario_ESTRUCTURA - copia.xlsm").Activate

Dim ini As String
ini = "A" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) + 1
Range(ini).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Workbooks("exportD.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

y este es el error que me marca en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que el problema está en la instancia de ``workbook = excel_macro.Workbooks.Open(Filename = excel_path, ReadOnly =1)`` es por eso que el atributo ``Save`` lo marca como ``None``.  Podrías poner una validación antes de guardar y ver si ahí está ocurriendo el problema ``if workbook != None: ``

Comment: buen día @FernandoCarraro , gracias por tu ayuda, pero fue mas error mío   y un poco de cansancio , pero en "Windows("Query_Diario_ESTRUCTURA - copia.xlsm").Activate", estaba llamando a un archivo diferente al que estaba abriendo por ello me daba el error, adiconal decidí omitir el guardado, pues en la macro de excel ya estaba haciendo el guardado previamente.

Answer (score 0):

error capa 8, estaba llamando un archivo diferente al que estaba abriendo en la línea Windows("Query_Diario_ESTRUCTURA - copia.xlsm").Activate.